# Recreation of Typeset Environment in Rudin's book

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I need to produce some mathematical notes and I would like to produce those notes in Rudin's style. The following are some excerpts from his book.
[image: An excerpt from the first page of a chapter in Rudin's book]

[image: Another excerpt from Rudin's book]

Specifically, I would like to know how to reproduce the typeset of the chapter and section headings (the font size and indentation), and also the numbered 'Theorem', 'Example', 'Definition', 'Remark' environments (these are just some examples).

I understand that it is nearly impossible to **exactly** recreate the same typeset, but it would be nice if someone can suggest any template that is similar to Rudin's style or even suggesting related settings and parameters only so that I can try those settings by myself. As I have no concrete ideas about where to start with, I have to apologize that I might not be able to provide any MWE.

In any case, I appreciate your patience in reading this post. If you do have some ideas to share about this topic, I am very happy to hear that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Can I suggest to look at the package `memoir` and its (wonderful) manual? I think you can get almost all what you ask here with it. Link: https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  This can be done with the `titlesec` package (see §3, *Advanced Interface*) and the `graphicx` package to scale chapter numbers.